# Write content which has comma to CSV file

Tags: java, string, file-io, csv, apache-poi

I am using Java. I have a requirement. I am getting 20000 records from database and I need to *write them into a CSV file.* The problem is the data that is retrieved from database has 22 columns and many values will have commas in them.

How can I write the values with comma into a CSV file using Java?

Also, I tried using Apache POI to write the data to excel, but it is taking a long time to write 20000 records. So, I am planning to write data into CSV file. Is this a good approach?

Comment: have you tried googling? :) there are a lot of results, e.g. [this seems ok](http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-40713.html)

Comment: *"taking a long time to write 20000 records. So, I am planning to write data into CSV file. Is this a good approach?"*  I doubt you could write code that writes it to a CSV much faster than Apache POI could write it to an Excel spreadsheet.  It might pay to use a profiler and check exactly where the time is being spent.

Answer (score 7):

Double quote the entire text field (column) if there's an embedded comma:

```
0, 1, "2,3", 4
```

It's not a bad idea to quote text values anyway.

Comment: and don't forget to quote your quotes if there is an embedded quote.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend that you use this nice library (that I did NOT write). http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/

It will handle all your CSV problems.